# How to make a source attachement in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Background: I am trying to use google analytics api's for java, to make their simple "helloAnalyticsApi" java code. But, I cannot even get past the basic steps of setting up eclipse and such.

Please see the link below:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#google-api-client

In that link, they say:

> Blockquote 
>   Eclipse users will want to set the "Source attachment" for each class jar to its corresponding "-sources" jar

I dont know this means. Please tell me how to do what they say in the above sentence. 
I tried a non-google tutorial, and it worked. But, when I try to make their sample java code, i get many errors which i mentioned in another post.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the API that is given.

1. Download the API that is given.
2. UNZIP the files in some directory
3. Make an eclipse Project say for example Analytics.
4. Goto the PROJECT tab click PROPERTIES and click on BUILD PATH
5. Click on ADD EXTERNAL JARS
6. Use the jars that you need for your project(Not all of them are REQUIRED).

you should be all set...

They have made simple steps really complicated by using the line
"Eclipse users will want to set the "Source attachment" for each class jar to its corresponding "-sources" jar..."

Comment: Really.........it would have never crossed my mind to do that.....that is amazingly simple if it works!